# Predicate logic: $(\forall x\varphi \rightarrow \forall x\psi ) \nRightarrow (\forall x(\varphi \rightarrow \psi))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Given $L$ language and $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are formulas.

Needs to show that is happening in general:
$$(\forall x\varphi \rightarrow \forall x\psi ) \nRightarrow (\forall x(\varphi \rightarrow  \psi))$$

I do not how to separate the right part and how to make it to the other part.
I'd be happy to suggest how to start working on the problem.

Comment: Maybe think about some examples.  "If every number is prime, then every number is even" ... this is true.  We cannot deduce "every prime number is even", which is false.

Comment: Btw, you probably mean $\not \vdash$ rather than $\not \implies$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One good way to think about this is in terms of sets. Think about $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as sets they define in some arbitrary $L$-structure.

Then $\forall x\varphi\rightarrow\forall x\psi$ is essentially saying "If $\varphi$ is everything, then $\psi$ is everything". On the other hand, $\forall x(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)$ says that "$\varphi$ is a subset of $\psi$".

Now find a structure where $\varphi$ is not a subset of $\psi$, but "if $\varphi$ is everything, then $\psi$ is everything" (e.g. neither is everything, but neither is a subset of the other).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I tell you, "If everyone cheats on the exam, then everyone will not get caught."

Can you conclude, "Everyone who cheats on the exam will not get caught" ?

No way, maybe you cheat but no one else does.  Then you might get caught.